# How to create private methods and ivars in Objective-C in iOS >= 4.0?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've heard that lately it's possible to create private methods by declaring the interface once again in the .m file. But what exactly is the syntax like?

If it matters: Under ARC.

- Must it appear right before @implementation?
- Does it look exactly like the @interface declaration in the .h file?
- Must it duplicate the information about inheritance and protocol compliance?
- Since when is this available? What's the oldest iOS and Objc-C runtime that supports it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Header file:

```
//YourClass.h:
@interface YourClass {
    @private //optional
    //private scope ivars
    @protected //default, optional
    //protected scope ivars
    @public //optional
    //public scope ivars
    @package //optional
    //package scope ivars
}

    //public methods

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
//YourClass.m:
#import "YourClass.h"

//you could also import this class extension (that's what it's called) from an
//external header file which can be helpful for making pseudo-protected methods/ivars
//Don't forget the additional import statement then, though.
@interface YourClass () <PrivateProtocol> //protocol tag optional, of cource

    @private //optional
    //private scope hidden ivars
    @protected //default, optional
    //protected scope hidden ivars
    @public //optional
    //public scope hidden ivars
    @package //optional
    //package scope hidden ivars

@end

@implementation YourClass

//your class' method implementations

@end
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127) on ivar scopes.

For more information on what's new in the above snippet and what it's all about (compatibility, etc) see the **[WWDC 2011 Session #322](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)**

Xcode 4.2 brought the hidden private ivars.
Class extensions have been around for quite a while.

Comment: Great! So the extension doesn't *have* to repeat protocol declarations in the .h file, and it also doesn't have to repeat the inheritance like YourClass : ThatSuperclass?

Comment: Nope. For more info on class extensions see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) and this [great article by bbum](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/). (Btw, class extensions have been around for quite a while now. Ivars declared in `@implementation` however only since Xcode 4.2)

Comment: Yes, since declaring properties is really just syntactic sugar for declaring accessor methods, you can declare them in a class extension.

Comment: Also keep in mind that with properties you don't need to declare the ivars at all. I hardly ever declare ivars anymore. Just synthesize them. Xcode will do an implicit declaration for you (they do exist at runtime, just not before compile time). Also Apple seems to be embracing this pattern: `@synthesize foo = _foo;` recently, which makes it easier to distinguish between ivar and accessor access. Also no need to write `- (void)setFoo:(id)someFoo`, anymore, just write `- (void)setFoo:(id)foo;`

Comment: The part about "pseudo-private ivars" is incorrect and dangerously so: If you declare a variable in the .m file below `@implementation` like so: `int _foo` everything will compile fine, but `_foo` will actually be a global variable (visible only in the implementation) instead of an ivar; in other words all instances of the class will share `_foo`!

Comment: @AndreasZollmann: Thanks, fixed it. Didn't know that actually (due to hardly ever using direct ivar access nowadays).